# Temperature as a function of energy in a container with ideal gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature

Let's consider a large container with insulating walls (not subjected to gravity) and with a large number of noninteracting particles (besides elastic collisions) for which I assume that the ergodic hypothesis is satisfied. I also assume that the particles don't have internal degrees of freedom and that they are classical.

This container has a small balloon inside, made from elastic material with good thermical conductance filled with the same kind of particles.

So the large container might be considered a heat bath and the probability density  of a state X of the particles inside the balloon will be proportional, according to Boltzmann distribution, to

$exp({- {E(X) \over kT} })$

where E(X) is the energy of the state X (only kinetic energy in our case), k is the Boltzmann constant, and T is the temperature.

For concreteness, let's assume that the total number of particles in the container is N, the number of particles inside the balloon is orders of magnitude smaller than N, the mass of each particle is $\mu$, and the total energy of all the particles in the container is $E_{total}$.

My question is how T depends on $E_{total}$, N, $\mu$ (I see no other parameters on which T might depend). Is there a concrete (even if asymptotic) formula?

Comment: Do you know the equation of state for ideal gas? The system is ideal gas, so the relation you are seeking is that equation of state, no?

Comment: @JánLalinský How would you derive the dependence of T on $E_{total}, N$ from $PV = mRT$? Besides, what I was interested in is in deriving T from first principles; by following Botond's answer, I found such derivation in https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~gros/Vorlesungen/TD/8_Microcanonical_ensemble.pdf .

Comment: Sorry, I meant the equation $U=c_V n T$ for ideal gas where $U$ is energy of the gas. This states gas energy is proportional to temperature and number of particles. This equation can be derived directly from the Boltzmann probability distribution which you mentioned: average translational kinetic energy of a molecule comes out $\frac{3}{2}k_B T$ and ideal gas has no other than kinetic energy of its molecules, so $U=\frac{3}{2}RnT$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temperature is set by your large container and is given by

$$\frac{1}{k T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial U}$$

where $S=S(U, V, n)$ is the container entropy and $U=\langle E \rangle$ is the internal energy. Since the container is large, $U \approx E_{total}$. You have thus to compute the entropy as a function of the internal energy. Its derivative gives the temperature.

The container is said to be in the microcanonical ensemble. Its entropy is given by $S=k \ln \Omega$ where $\Omega=\Omega(E_{total}, V, n)$ is the number of states available to the system. The problem runs under the name "ideal gas in microcanonical ensemble" in statistical mechanics textbooks. For non-interacting, point-like particles $\Omega(E, V, n) \sim U^{3n/2} V^n$ thus $T$ will only depend on $E_{total}$ and $n$. You then get the ideal gas energy: $E=(3/2)nkT$ thus $T = (2/3) E/nk$

Note: by container there I mean the container, except the balloon.

Comment: I don't understand: if I take the last formula for $\Omega(E,V,n)$ and plug it into $S=k ln\Omega$, the partial derivative of S with respect to U does not depend on V, so accordingly T should not depend on V. Where is my mistake?

Comment: you're right, I corrected